# Is there a lock statement in PowerShell

Tags: multithreading, powershell, locking

When using threads in PowerShell, are we able to use the `lock` statement like in C#?

Or do we need to use the code that `lock` gets pre compiled to, ie. use the `Monitor` class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no native `lock` statement in PowerShell as such, but you can acquire\release an exclusive lock on a specified object using [Monitor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Monitor.aspx). It can be used to pass data between threads when working with Runspaces, which is demonstrated in David Wyatt's blog post [Thread Synchronization (in PowerShell?)](https://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/thread-synchronization-in-powershell).

Quote:

> MSDN page for [ICollection.IsSynchronized Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.issynchronized.aspx) mentions that you must explicitly lock the SyncRoot property of an Collection to perform a thread-safe enumeration of its contents, even if you're dealing with a Synchronized collection.

Basic example:

```powershell
# Create synchronized hashtable for thread communication
$SyncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{Test='Test'})

try
{
    # Lock it
    [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($SyncHash)
    $LockTaken = $true

    foreach ($keyValuePair in $SyncHash.GetEnumerator())
    {
        # Hashtable is locked, do something
        $keyValuePair
    }
}
catch
{
    # Catch exception
    throw 'Lock failed!'
}
finally
{
    if ($LockTaken)
    {
        # Release lock
        [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($SyncHash)
    }
}
```

David has also written fully functional [Lock-Object](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Lock-Object-Synchronize-725ef5e7) module, which implements this approach.

Comment: While possible (and an up-vote because this functions for all .NET including C# on equally rare occasion), I would be pressed to find a good PS usage case of such, given its "power domain" .. a system/named semaphore may be useful .. maybe .. [Also there may be some fine print with assignment to $LockTaken.]